# MongoDB aggregation pipeline for dating / chat app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a MERN stack web application with a Node.JS / MongoDB backend.

I'm building a chat inbox that displays the User's most recent conversations, and previews the most recent message in that conversation.

I am trying to create a MongoDB aggregation that finds the 12 most recent "conversations" and returns the most recent chat in that conversation and attaches the associated user.

The pipeline involves two database collections:

- User collection (Documents of each user)
- Chat collection (Documents of each message sent)

The goal of the aggregation pipeline is to return the Most Recent Chats (sent or received) and attach the associated User from the User Collection

The Chat schema is structured as follows:

```
{ 
sender: (User Document ID of the sender),
receiver: (User Document ID of the receiver),
timestamp: (Date Message Was Sent)
}
```

Here is the pipeline I have built so far. Note: userid variable is the ObjectID of the requesting user.

```
 var findUserMessages = await Chat.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    receiver: userid,
  },
},
{ $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$sender",
    createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
    isRead: { $first: "$isRead" },
    chat_id: { $first: "$_id" },
    message: { $first: "$message" },
  },
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: "$chat_id",
    createdAt: "$createdAt",
    isRead: "$isRead",
    senderId: "$_id",
    message: 1,
  },
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "senderId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "user",
  },
},
{ $unwind: "$user" },
{ $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
{ $skip: skip },
{ $limit: 12 },
]);
```

The problem is this aggregation returns the most recent message where the userid is the receiver. I need it to return the most recent message where the user is the sender OR receiver.

I tried this in the match stage:

```
  $match: {
    $or: [{ sender: userid }, { receiver: userid }],
  },
```

However in the groupstage, I believe I now need the ID to be conditional based on if the user is the sender or receiver. If the user is the sender, the group ID should be the receiver, and vice versa.

```
 {
  $group: {
    _id: "$sender",
    createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
    isRead: { $first: "$isRead" },
    chat_id: { $first: "$_id" },
    message: { $first: "$message" },
  },
},
```

This is where I got stuck. I've tried hiring a few code mentors and no one has been able to solve this problem.

Goal: should return most recent chat (Quantity: 1) from each conversation, sorted by most recent, with associated User attached

- Step One: Find All Chats Where User is Sender or Receiver
- Step Two: Sort By Most Recent
- Step Three: Group By Conversation
- Step Four: Get Most Recent Chat By Conversation
- Step Five: Find Associated Other User and Unwind

Comment: Your question is way too big. Better if you could break this into several questions.

Comment: I suggest that you should store the necessary data separately to help with query. If your use case is a chat app. you could potentially have too much data and traffic to do such complex aggregation

Comment: I see in your aggregation that you use other fields not present in the schema, please also include them in the schema for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned here

> However in the groupstage, I believe I now need the ID to be conditional based on if the user is the sender or receiver. If the user is the sender, the group ID should be the receiver, and vice versa.

The key is to set a new field according to the condition using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```
[{
  $match: {
    $or: [{ sender: userid }, { receiver: userid }],
  }
}, {
  $addFields: { // set friendId as receiver, if user is sender and vice versa
    friendId: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$sender', userId] }, '$receiver', '$sender' ] }
  }
}, {
  $sort: { createdAt: -1 } // you have timestamp in the schema but using createdAt, I'll keep it like in your aggregation
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: '$friendId', // use the new field to group
    createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
    isRead: { $first: "$isRead" },
    chatId: { $first: "$_id" },
    message: { $first: "$message" },
  }
}, {
  $addFields: {
    _id: '$chatId',
    friendId: '$_id',
  }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "$friendId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "user",
  },
}, {
  $unwind: '$user'
}, {
  $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
}, {
  $skip: skip
}, { 
  $limit: 12
}]
```

As I have mentioned in the comment on your question, it's better to keep useful information separately to help with the query. For example you could have another collection that keep track of "discussions", which will be unique amongst each pair of sender and receiver, you could even add the recent message and timestamp in the discussion collection.